# undefined method `is_admin?' for #<User:0x007fc2b3f952e0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model User and Role.

USER belongs_to ROLE as you can see in this models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role

  # this method return true or false
  def is_admin?
    self.role.name == 'admin'
  end

end


class Role < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
end
```

The role_id exists in User table

But when i try access 'is_admin?' method in rails console, the "undefined method `is_admin?' for #" appears

```
u = User.find_by_email('teste@teste.com')

=> #<User id: 2, email: "teste@teste.com", created_at: "2017-05-30 16:57:57", updated_at: "2017-05-30 17:00:44", role_id: 6>

u.is_admin?

NoMethodError: undefined method `is_admin?' for #<User:0x007fd5233c1ab8
```

How can i do this?

Comment: do a `reload!` and try again?

Comment: @wesley6j is right.  To elaborate, every time you add methods in a model or change the DB structure, you need to run `reload!` in your Rails console to see the changes.

Comment: Nothing change, the same error occurs @wesley6j

Comment: Try quitting the rails console.

Comment: Shouldn't your model be like `class User < ActiveRecord::Base`, is it a typo?

Comment: Or you tagged it wrong, you are on rails 5..

Comment: I tried with self.is_admin? and without self, but it did not work. I don't know what i need to do

Comment: Restarted the console? And which version of rails you using?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon  Rails 5.0.3 | ruby 2.2.4-p230

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but i solved this issue in this way

I simply created another method and now it worked

```
  def has_role role
    self.role.name == role
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using rolify gem for roles? If yes then follow this:

If you want to check for is_admin? then modify your is_admin? method as:->

```
def is_admin?
   has_role?('admin')
end
```

then try this

```
u = User.find_by_email('teste@teste.com')
u.is_admin?
```

if user don't have 'admin' role then you can assign by :->

```
u.add_role :admin
```